# How can I create a new file with the words that contains only lower case from another file with linux commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

More exactly, I have to write a shell script which move the words that contains only lower case from one file to another. The words from new file have to be sorted alphabetically and the duplicate lines have to be removed.

Till now I tried:

```
grep -E '^\b[a-z]*[a-z]\b' file1.txt | sort -V | cat > file2.txt | awk ' !seen[$0]++' file2.txt
```

file1.txt:

```
aaaAaa B
aaccc c
aP ppp
aAaaA
aa
aAaa
AAa
aa
```

file2.txt will be:

```
aa
aa
aaccc c
```

the terminal will print:

```
aa
aaccc c
```

Comment: Rather than "the terminal will print", it is more appropriate to say "the following is written to the terminal".

Comment: At first glance, it appears that you have a solution that works.  So what is the question?

Comment: `sort -uV` will take care of the uniqueness in one go.

Comment: Hello William, if you look at the third row, you will see that there is another word with lowercase. My command takes only rows that contains all words with lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous.

It's unclear if you want to **move** strings from `file1.txt` to `file2.txt`, or just extract / copy matching strings from `file1.txt` to `file2.txt`.

You also state you want to match lowercase **words**, but your example suggests that you want to match any line of text that contains only lowercase letters with optional spaces.

Assuming you only want to extract (versus moving) matching strings, and you want to match any line that contains only lowercase characters with optional spaces, this should do what you want:

`egrep '^[a-z[:space:]]+$' file1.txt | grep '[a-z]' | sort | tee file2.txt | uniq`

You should get the following result:

```
nicolaw@host:~ $ cat file1.txt
aaaAaa B
aaccc c
aP ppp
aAaaA
aa
aAaa
AAa
aa
nicolaw@host:~ $ egrep '^[a-z[:space:]]+$' file1.txt | grep '[a-z]' | sort | tee file2.txt | uniq
aa
aaccc c
nicolaw@host:~ $ cat file2.txt
aa
aa
aaccc c
nicolaw@host:~ $
```

Alternatively, if you are more interested in just the lowercase **words**, (versus whole lines that only contain lowercase or spaces), then you will want something like this:

`egrep -ow '[a-z]+' file1.txt | sort | tee file2.txt | uniq`

Which should output something like this:

```
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ cat file1.txt
aaaAaa B
aaccc c
aP ppp
aAaaA
aa
aAaa
AAa
aa
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ egrep -ow '[a-z]+' file1.txt | sort | tee file2.txt | uniq
aa
aaccc
c
ppp
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ cat file2.txt
aa
aa
aaccc
c
ppp
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $
```

Comment: Hi Neech, For example, if file1.txt has only one row " Mike eats an an apple" , file2.txt has to be filled with " an apple eats ".

Comment: Okay. If I'm understanding correctly, you're more interested in each lowercase **word** rather than lines that only contain lowercase letters.

I think this should do what you want: `egrep -ow '[a-z]+' file1.txt | sort | tee file2.txt | uniq`

Answer (score 0):

**awk** approach

```
awk '/^[a-z ]*$/' file1.txt  | sort | uniq > file2.txt
```

Sample output:

```
cat file2
aa
aaccc c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for w in `cat startingFile`; do x=`echo $w | sed -r 's@[a-z]+@@g'`; if (( ${#w} > 0 && ${#x} == 0 )); then echo $w; fi; done | sort | uniq > allDone
```

The grave accents, slantly quotes, are not showing when I post this. They belong around "cat startingFile" and "echo $w | sed -r 's@[a-z]+@@g'"

Comment: Just toss 4 spaces in front of your code and it will format as code so the backticks will be retained.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that you are not interested in lines that are all lower case, but individual words, I think an `awk` solution like the following will get you close:

```
$ cat infile.txt
aaaAaa B
aaccc c
aP ppp
aAaaA
aa
aAaa
AAa
aa
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if ($i~/^[a-z]*$/){print $i}}}' infile.txt | sort -uV
aa
aaccc
c
ppp
```

You could write the output to a file within the awk script as well:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if ($i~/^[a-z]*$/){print $i ; print $i > "outfile.txt"}}}' infile.txt | sort -uV
```

This script is looping through each field/word in the line and testing for all lowercase using the regex. The result is printed as it's own line and it's all piped to `sort` with the `u` flag for `unique`.

Comment: If I want to put the words you printed in a file, should I use { cat $i >> newfile.txt } instead of { print $i } ? Currently, I don't have access to a linux terminal and I can't check it on myself.

Comment: If you want the words that are currently printed to the terminal in a file, then just redirect the whole thing (from the first answer) into a file `awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if ($i~/^[a-z]*$/){print $i}}}' infile.txt | sort -uV > outfile.txt`.  You can use tee to print and redirect like `awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if ($i~/^[a-z]*$/){print $i}}}' infile.txt | sort -uV | tee outfile.txt`.

Comment: So with that last `awk infile.txt | sort | tee outfile.txt` awk is carving up the file word by word, testing it for lowercase and piping to sort, which grabs uniques and sorts alphabetically, then tee gets it and sends it to the stdout (terminal) as well as the outfile.txt.

Comment: You can also redirect the lowercase words before the pipe to sort by using that second `awk` script. ` print $i > outfile.txt ` in the awk script says send the value that passed the regex test to the file instead of outputting to stdout. There are two `print $i` in that script, one to send to the file and one to send to stdout so `sort -uV` can do it's thing to the terminal output version. It's a lot of ins and outs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you want to retain the original line numbering (eg, if the input is `foo bar`, if you want `foo` and `bar` on different lines in the output), but if that is acceptable then it is common to pre-process the data to put all words on their own line.  Bear in mind that this solution takes a very naive approach to this problem and assumes spaces indicate word boundaries, but you can easily modify as necessary.  Basically, you put each word on its own line and then solve the problem on a line by line basis:

```
< file1.txt tr ' ' \\n | grep '^[a-z]*$' | sort -u
```

Otoh, you can probably just modify what you have slightly and use:

```
grep -Eo '\b[a-z]+\b' file1.txt
```

or

```
grep -Eow '[a-z]+' file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` command has a very handy option `-v` that says to select records that **do not** match the pattern.  So, with that in mind, this will get you your output file:

```
grep -v "[A-Z]" file1.txt |sort > file2.txt
```

Here's a sample run, with the addition of displaying the contents sans dups:

```
StackOverflow> cat file1.txt
aaaAaa B
aaccc c
aP ppp
aAaaA
aa
aAaa
AAa
aa

StackOverflow> grep -v "[A-Z]" file1.txt |sort > file2.txt

StackOverflow> cat file2.txt
aa
aa
aaccc c

StackOverflow> cat file2.txt | sort -u
aa
aaccc c

StackOverflow>
```

The first command simply shows what's in `file1.txt`.  The next command uses `grep` to find all lines that don't have an uppercase letter (the `-v` option) and pipes that to sort which writes it to `file2.txt`.  I showed what's in that file, then did it again using `sort` to eliminate the duplicates.

Note that to accomplish what you want, you only need the two lines:

```
grep -v "[A-Z]" file1.txt |sort > file2.txt
cat file2.txt | sort -u
```

**Edit:** I was focused on the `sort` command and didn't think about the better `uniq` option for the second line.  Instead of using `sort -u`, you could do this:

```
uniq file2.txt
```

making the whole shebang:

```
grep -v "[A-Z]" file1.txt |sort > file2.txt
uniq file2.txt
```

Hope this helps!